# Creating a new file that has one line added to to the first line and one line added to the last

Tags: bash, cat

I need help or I will do this is python instead (by reading one line at a time) which I know I should not need to.

I have large number of text files that I get using find.

```
FILES=$(find ... -iname "*.txt")
num=0
for doc in $FILES; do
     echo "start string" > cat $doc > echo "end string" > "outfile$num.txt"
     let num=num+1
done
```

I dont know to many unix commands, but what I want to do is something like this:

output "start string" then cat $doc then "end string" to stdout and store in the outfile.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
{echo "start string"; cat $doc; echo "end string"} > "outfile$num.txt"
```

Or alternatively:

```
echo "start string" > "outfile$num.txt"
cat $doc >> "outfile$num.txt"
echo "end string" >> "outfile$num.txt"
```

Or yet another example using sed (you can do something similar with awk):

```
sed -e '1i start string;$a end string' $doc > "outfile$num.txt"
```

In the first example the three commands are simply executed sequentially and the output is then fed as a whole to the output redirect `> "outfile$num.txt"`.

In the second example we do it in three commands and use the `>>` operator instead of the `>` operator to concatenate the output to the given file instead of replace the given file with the output.

Also, as an aside, you should be careful with your use of `for doc in $FILES`, this splits on spaces, so if any of your filenames contain spaces they will be interpreted as multiple file names instead of one file name.

Comment: Thank you, regrettably I have too much work to do (and too little time) to read up on Unix and different utility programs.

Even though my question was probably a dumb question, stress really makes you not think clearly. You have made my day much better, thanks again! :)

Comment: The first example needs a little tweaking: `{ echo ...; cat $doc; echo ...; }`. Spaces to separate the braces from the contents, and a required semicolon after the last echo.